# SQL Server instance seems hung, restarting state shows 'change pending...'

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am having trouble with my SQL Server 2008 R2 instance.

First, one of my databases on this instance seems to have crashed. When I try to drop it, I am getting the error message below.

> Msg 3702, Level 16, State 3, Line 2
>
> Cannot drop database “DataBaseName” because it is currently in use.

I needed to drop the crashed database and recreate it from scratch. I couldn't rename it either.

Now I try to restart the instance and it seems to hung, with the State column showing 'change pending...'

What's acting up?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a large change is being made to a table's schema.

When you view the database in SQL Server Management Studio's object explorer, what does it say next to the database?

If you delete the database from the object explorer there should be a check box you can click that will automatically close all the connections to the database before dropping it.